# Retrieving Contact Object By Email?

Tags: contact, salesforceiq

I'm trying to see if it's possible to use SalesforceIQ's API to retrieve a `Contact` object by email (instead of by ID).  As it is, I have to get *all* of my `Contact` objects and loop through them to find one with an email that matches.

I figure there might be a better way.  Is there?  (If it matters, I'm using Python)

Comment: From a quick search, I didn't find any documentation on the SalesforceIQ API (as expected with subscription based software), but I would imagine this is definitely possible. Do you have the documentation or the Python snippet you're using to query by record ID?

Comment: @BrianMansfield The documentation I'm looking at is here: https://api.salesforceiq.com/#/python#documentation_contacts_get-a-single-contact and it explains how I'd get a single contact using the ID.  It's just Contact(my_contact_id).  Doesn't look like such a thing exists for email, though but figured I'd ask!

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for the method states:

> Get a Single Contact A GET request which pulls a specific Contact by
>   ID, Email or Phone Number

The curl example looks like this:

```
curl 'https://api.salesforceiq.com/v2/contacts?properties.email=tom@salesforceiq.com'
```

SalesforceIQ may determine the query type based on input, try this:

```
from relateiq.client import RelateIQ
from relateiq.contacts import Contact
RelateIQ("[API Key]", "[API Secret]")
contact = Contact("email=jon@gmail.com")
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but, unfortunately, it sets the email as the ID.  I ran:  contact_object = Contact(my_email), print contact_object

Comment: @bclayman the curl example in their docs uses email, I updated my response, can you try that?

Comment: Sure thing.  Just did but it just sets the id as "email=jon@gmail.com" :(